# Cannot type @ symbol

Tags: flash, keyboard

Having an issue that I have never encountered before. On Firefox PC I cannot type the @ symbol in an input textfield. Obviously we have embedded the fonts correctly with the symbols, and it works fine on mac and on other browsers on PC - it is only on firefox 3.6 on Windows 7. Flash 10.0.45.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change your keyboard settings to English.  We had this problem at my last job, but I was never able to get time to get to the bottom of it.  It only occurs on keyboards that are not set to English.